# Pasar valor de un for a otro for

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo estos 2 *ciclos* `for`, necesito pasar el valor de la variable `disxd` del primer *ciclo* `for` a la variable `disxd` del segundo *ciclo* `for`

```js
var distancia, aux = 0;
arrText2.splice(0, 1);
arrText1.pop();
var disxd = [];
var distanciaCentro, aux8 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {
  parseFloat(arrText[i]);
  distancia = (arrText[i] + aux) / escala;
  aux = aux + arrText[i];
  var altos = 68;
  var disxd = (aux - 250) / escala;
  var image = document.getElementById('screem');
  ctx.drawImage(image, 80 + disxd, 67);

}
//Centro de sanitarios
for (var i = 0; i < arrText1.length; i++) {
  parseFloat(arrText1[i]);
  if (i === 0) {
    distanciaCentro = arrText1[i] + (arrText2[i]) / 2
  } else {
    if (i => 1) {
      distanciaCentro = (arrText1[i]) / 2 + (arrText2[i]) / 2
    }
  }
  var disxd = (aux - 250) / escala;
  /*Info Ancho cubículo individual*/
  ctx.font = '16px Arial';
  ctx.fillText(distanciaCentro, 95 + disxd, 120);
}
```

Comment: El bucle for en JavaScript es síncrono|bloquenante. Solo guarda dicha variable fuera del primer for para que esté disponible en el segundo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas usar el valor con el que quedó luego de salir del primer for, no vuelvas a declararla.

En vez de

```
 var disxd = (aux - 250) / escala;
```

Guarda su valor en otra variable

```
 var disxd2 = disxd;
```

O en todo caso, le asignas lo que ya tenía antes de seguir con el calculo

```
disxd += (aux - 250) / escala;
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Pero solo me guarda el ultimo valor, necesito que me guarde todos los valores.

Comment: Entonces podrías hacer un arreglo de dos dimensiones y utilizar el i del for como índice

Comment: me sirvio hacer un arreglo de dos dimensiones, Muchas gracias

Comment: me regalas los puntitos de la respuesta? soy nuevo y estoy intentando aumentar mi reputacion